# unbound identifier in module

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to complete two arrays. For example, there is l1 like '(1 2 3), and another is l2 like '(2 1 3). It should return #t. But there is error when I run it. set-euqal?: unbound identifier in module in: set-euqal?

```
(define check_length
    (lambda (a b)
        (cond
          ((= a b)#t)
          ((> a b)#f)
          ((< a b)#f))))

(define (subset? l1 l2)
    (or (null? l1)
        (and (member  (car l1) l2)
             (subset? (cdr l1) l2))))

(define (set-equal? l1 l2)
    (and (subset? l1 l2)
         (subset? l2 l1)))

(define equals
    (lambda (BST value)
         (cond
           ((bst-isempty? BST) #f)
           ((check_length (length BST) (length value)))
           ((set-euqal? (BST) (value)))
           (else #f))))
```

Comment: You have a typo on the second to last line: you spelled the function `set-euqal?` instead of `set-equal?`. If you are using DrRacket, it should highlight such errors in red when you try to run the program.

Comment: I can only see the  definition for `set-equal` so it's probably right that you have not defined the function `set-euqal`. Probably a misspelling. When fixed that you are calling `BST` as a function by wrapping the variable in parentheses. What do you expect `(BST)` to do? You do the same with `value` and since you call `length` on it is should be a list and not a function. You cannot just wrap things in parentheses. Imagine a variable called `num` that is bound to `5` in an Algol language. What would `num()` do?